# How to decrypt WhatsApp iCloud backup

Tags: icloud, backup, keychain, encryption, whatsapp.app

I downloaded my old WhatsApp chat history from iCloud which is encrypted.

The SQLite file I am trying to open is ChatStorage.sqlite.enc which asks for a password to open but not sure how to decrypt that file.

Also, find a password in the keychain which is net.whatsapp.RecoveryToken, but that is also protected, so that didn't help either.

So I have access to my phone, my iCloud account, the WhatsApp application which is linked to the same phone number, the keychain of my mac, but somehow can't find a way to open that encrypted old backup of mine.

Comment: WhatsApp uses iOS Data Protection to encrypt user data files (including ChatStorage.sqlite) using the device-specific and unrecoverable hardware UID key as well as a key derived from the user's passcode. It may not be decrypted without physical access to the specific iOS device that created the file as well as knowledge of the user's passcode.

Comment: Yes but I own the phone and have access to it, and also I downloaded that SQLite file. I just need a method to decrypt it. It is already stored as a backup on my WhatsApp but I don't want it to override the existing history and opening the SQLite would be enough for me.

Comment: Does the data exist on the iPhone in WhatsApp or are you trying to recover it from a backup? You should probably perform a full backup to a PC with iTunes or to a Mac and do not encrypt the backup.  Then you should be able to access the SQLite file.  Currently, the copy you have is encrypted by iOS.

Comment: This backup exists as the active WhatsApp backup, inside the app, actually stored in iCloud. The current WhatsApp history I use is different so it will back up the local one instead of the iCloud backup.

Comment: Any news on  this matter? I have copied the backup files from iCloud drive but most of them end with `.enc`, since I turned end-to-end encryption on. I do know, however, the password that I set for the backup. Should be possible to decrypt it on the Mac?